# Should a Rails app have to work in jRuby, when I want to deploy it via warble on a Java application Server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, jrubyonrails

I want to make sure, the app will work properly before I "warble" it. Does it have to work in jRuby for that or does it work anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally it should work without a problem, but ... there are a few but's :)

- jruby does not support all gems
- it depends on the ruby version you developed against, it is not 1.9 compatible yet
- i am not sure, but interacting with the system will not work in the same way i presume (e.g. calling batch-scripts, starting executables, ...)

But if you don't do anything out of the ordinary, i guess it would not be a problem.

That said, i think it is good practice to develop, or at least test, your application in the same environment (os/ruby-version) as your deployment platform.

Comment: Thank you! BTW: I am using ruby 1.8.5 on Redhat. On development and production. The rails app is a very basic one (no gems or advanced stuff).

Comment: So have you tried it? Sounds like it could work. Ruby 1.8.5 is old though, i would recommend upgrading to 1.8.7.